# Axiom of regularity and constructible sets

Tags: set-theory, axioms

I am studying the book "Set Theory and the Continuum Hypothesis" by Paul J. Cohen and in the Chapter III he proves a theorem which says:

> If $A$ is any axiom of $ZF$, then $A_L$ is provable in $ZF$.

(Explaining the notation: Here $L$ denote the "classe" of constructible sets, and $A_L$ is relativization the Axiom to $L$. 
The Axiom means intuitively that the constructible sets are a model for ZF.)

For that prove Cohen just showed that a constructible set satisfy each axiom of $ZF$, but the Axiom Regularity he left as exercise. **How we can prove the Axiom of Regularity for constructible sets?**

Comment: Please consider adding a line explaining the notation. (It is more common to denote relativizations by superindices.)

Comment: Ok, I will do it. Thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: Incidentally, I'd recommend against using Cohen's book to learn this material - more modern texts are much clearer.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Can you recommend some?

Comment: @Math97 Kunen's book "Set theory and independence proofs" is really quite good, as is Jech's book.

Comment: @NoahSchweber thank you very much.

Comment: In addition to what @Noah said, Halbeisen's book "Combinatorial Set Theory" is great.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regularity has the form "$\forall x\exists y\theta(x,y)$" for a particular formula $\theta$ (as do most of the ZF axioms). The easiest way to show that such a statement $\alpha$ which holds in a structure $M$ also holds in a substructure $N\subseteq M$ is to "push down to $N$" directly:

- Suppose $u\in N$; we want to find some $v\in N$ such that $N\models\theta(u,v)$.
- Since $u\in N$ and $N\subseteq M$, we know $u\in M$; since $M\models\forall x\exists y\theta(x,y)$ there is some $v\in M$ such that $M\models\theta(u,v)$.
- Now we'd be really happy if we could conclude two things:

  - $v$ is also in $N$ (a priori all we know right now is $v\in M$).
  - $N\models\theta(u,v)$ as well (a priori all we know right now is $M\models\theta(u,,v)$).

*Neither* of those last two sub-bulletpoints is true **in general** ... but in the specific case of regularity, they do hold (the key point for the first being that $L$ is **transitive**, and the key point for the second being that all the quantifiers inside $\theta$ are **bounded**).

---

### A technical coda:

Incidentally, these ideas will come back with a vengeance when we start talking about **absoluteness** - under what general conditions can we "transfer" a property of $V$ to $L$ or between more general inner models *(= transitive proper classes satisfying ZF)*? For example:

- ZF proves "every well-ordering is isomorphic to an ordinal." This means that if $M$ is any inner model (say $M=L$) then $M$ is "correct about well-orderedness:" if $R$ is a linear order in $M$ and $M\models$ "$R$ is a well-ordering" then $R$ is in fact a well-ordering. This is **Mostowski absoluteness**.
- A special case of Mostowski absoluteness is the absoluteness between inner models of $\Pi^1_1$ statements. (This is important enough that it's also often called "Mostowski absoluteness.") We can surprisingly strengthen this special case through a clever application of (the general version of) Mostowski absoluteness: $\Pi^1_2$ sentences are absolute between inner models. This is **Shoenfield absoluteness**, and is unfortunately too complicated to prove here.
- It turns out that we can't push beyond $\Pi^1_2$ in ZF alone: the sentence "Every real is constructible" is $\Pi^1_3$ and not necessarily absolute since $ZF\not\vdash V=L$. However, [additional set-theoretic axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_cardinal) do yield this and further strengthenings by generalizing the proof of Shoenfield absoluteness.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

$L$ is transitive and $\forall x,y \in L\,(x \cap y\in L).$ So $\forall x\in L\, \forall y\, (y\in x \iff (y\in L\land y\in x)\iff ((y\in L\land (y\in x)^L)\,))$ and also $\forall x,y \in L\, (x\cap y= (x\cap y)^L).$

For all $z\in L$ we have $z\ne \emptyset \iff (z\ne \emptyset)^L.$

If $L$ did not satisfy Regularity (a.k.a. Foundation) we would have $$(\exists x\,(x\ne \emptyset \land \forall y \,(y\in x \implies y\cap x\ne \emptyset)\,))^L\iff$$  $$ \iff \exists x\in L\,((x\ne \emptyset)^L \land \forall y\in L\,( (y\in x)^L\implies ((y\cap x\ne \emptyset)^L\,))) \iff$$ $$ \iff \exists x\in L\, (x\ne \emptyset \land \forall y\, (\,(y\in L\land y\in x)\implies (y\cap x \ne \emptyset)\,)) \iff$$ $$ \iff \exists x\in L\,(x\ne \emptyset \land \forall y\, (y\in x\implies y\cap x \ne \emptyset)\,) \implies$$ $$ \implies \exists x\, (x\ne \emptyset \land \forall y\, (y\in x\implies y\cap x\ne \emptyset))$$ which violates Regularity in $V$ (the universe).